# Creating a Custom ReLU that works on specific pixels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to create a custom ReLU function that takes a vector `V` that holds 2D locations of pixels i.e `[[1, 3], [1,1] ..]`

and performs a ReLU operation on those pixels across all channels.

the input_tensor is a tensor after it passes through a `Conv2D`  layer - so its shape is: `(None, 30, 30, 16)`

(original image is `32x32x3`)

my code (I know it won't actually return an altered input_tensor, it's just to sort some of the first problems i've encountered) :

```
def relu(x):
    if x > 0:
        return x
    else:
        return 0


class Custom_ReLU(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Custom_ReLU, self).__init__()

    def call(self, input_tensor, V=None):
        for i in range(len(V)):
            relu(input_tensor[ V[i] ])

        return input_tensor
```

When running this I get an error that I pass a tensor into relu - so my indexing is incorrect, but I tried indexing it differently and I got nowhere:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "custom__re_lu" (type Custom_ReLU).
        
        in user code:
        
            File "/home/adav/prog/tf/main.py", line 63, in call  *
                relu(input_tensor[ V[i][0], V[i][1] ])
            File "/home/adav/prog/tf/main.py", line 51, in relu  *
                if x > 0:
        
            ValueError: condition of if statement expected to be `tf.bool` scalar, got Tensor("my_model/custom__re_lu/Greater:0", shape=(30, 16), dtype=bool); to check for None, use `is not None`
        
        
        Call arguments received:
          • input_tensor=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 30, 30, 16), dtype=float32)
          • V=array([[ 1,  1],
               [ 1,  4],
               [ 1,  7],
.
.
.
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Where does `V` come from?

Comment: I'm Hard coding it for now like this: ```self.V = np.array([(i, j) for i in range(1,29,3) for j in range(1,29,3)]) ```, When I plug input_tensor into the customReLU I pass in self.V aswell

Comment: Why is there a need for a custom layer? I think this make no sense, your code looks like the standard relu implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `tf.gather_nd` and `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class Custom_ReLU(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Custom_ReLU, self).__init__()

  def call(self, inputs):
    shape = tf.shape(inputs)

    V = tf.stack([(i, j) for i in tf.range(1,29,3) for j in tf.range(1,29,3)])
    indices = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(tf.repeat(tf.range(0, shape[0]), repeats=tf.shape(V)[0]), axis=-1), tf.tile(V, [shape[0],1])], axis=-1)
    y = tf.gather_nd(inputs, indices)
    y = tf.where(tf.greater(y, 0.0), y, tf.constant(0.0))
    return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(x, indices, y)


custom_relu = Custom_ReLU()
x = tf.random.normal((2, 30, 30, 16))
print(custom_relu(x))
```

Run a few iterations with a smaller tensor to see how the values change.

Comment: Yes, Is there a way to store the ReLU decision for each pixel instead of directly altering the input tensor?
I evetually want to affect the entire patch around the pixel based on the ReLU value it gets.

Comment: The decision is in the variable `y`